firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.1 uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease FAILED
classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.1")
AGP 8.3.2-8.4.1(No other versions were tested)
AS Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1
Generate Signed App Bundle
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease' (type 'UploadMappingFileTask').

Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/xxx/myapp/app/build/gmpAppId.txt'.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 2m 6s
classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9") is ok for me.
